# Change html table background color for even rows

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm using https://datatables.net/ tables in an asp.net mvc application & would like to change the background color for even rows BUT only for the first column.

The styling should also only apply to the table body but not the table head.

I have the below CSS but its changing the background color for even rows for the entire row, how can apply it only to the fist column in the even row?

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #e0f0ff;    
}
```

Comment: .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) td:first-child{}

Comment: why not put a class on the tr and get rid of the bits before?

Comment: @Nick thank you for the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is you answer:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) td:first-child{background-color: #e0f0ff;    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tr` you can use `td` for background

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) td:first-child {
    background-color: #e0f0ff;    
}
```

Comment: You're missing something essential: (taken from question) " _background color for even rows **BUT only for the first column**._ "

Answer (score 0):

You can use ":first-child".

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #e0f0ff;    
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```